# how to fix npm run build failed to compile react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/Users/qadeer/Desktop/Khazan/guardman/src'
Did you mean 'App.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './App' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
this is the issue i am getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3hEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Into **module.rules** add:

```
    {
            test: /\.m?js/,
            resolve: {
              fullySpecified: false
            }
        },
```